# Compile error when running Go source code in Goland

Tags: go, goland

**Background**.

Currently I want to contribute to the [golang/go](https://github.com/golang/go) project. But When open this project in Goland, I found a lot of compile error such as `tar_test.go:11:2: use of internal package internal/testenv not allowed`. But When I ran execute `./all.bash` under `src` directory, it shows `ALL TESTS PASSED`. So I got confused, what steps I have missed, how can I run source code/test properly in Goland/vscode.

**Env Info**
go env

```
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/apple1/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/apple1/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/apple1/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.19.2/global/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/apple1/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.19.2/global"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io"
GOROOT="/Users/apple1/go/go1.18.7"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/Users/apple1/go/go1.18.7/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.7"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/w4/f3kl6pmx4mxbhggc6s7fhrhh0000gp/T/go-build955434052=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

go source code path

```
/Users/apple1/develop/go
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see a guide on how to configure GoLand to contribute Go project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/how-to-use-goland-to-contribute-to-go.html

Especially, pay attention to the 2 and 3 steps. You should compile Go and specify it in the settings: *Preferences | Go | GOROOT* to avoid false-positive errors.